# Как сделать так, чтобы фрейм был всегда поверх других окон?

Tags: java, jframe

Я хочу, что бы мой фрейм ВСЕГДА был поверх остальных окон.

Пробовал метод `setAlwaysOnTop()` вставил и в `main`, и в класс, открывается он поверх остальных окон, а мне нужно, чтобы он был поверх других окон всегда. Возможно вообще это реализовать? Если есть у кого-то идеи или документация почитать, поделитесь пожалуйста.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class gui extends JFrame {

    public void bar() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        frame.add(label);
        label.setText("будущий прогресс бар");
        label.setBounds(0,0,500,250);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        Dimension display = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();


        frame.setLocation( 1420,780);

        // frame.setLocation(1420,780);
        // (display.height - % * display.height  ,display.width - % * display.width  );

        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);         // Выравнивание содержимого по вертикали
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);       // Выравнивание содержимого по горизонтали

        setAlwaysOnTop(true);                              // Поверх всех окон
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю что требуется обозначить фокус на этом окошке. Если я Вас правильно понимаю, вот [статья](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30529666/21572397) на английском, но думаю там и так всё понятно

Comment: @ordinal, спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте, если поможет, дайте знать

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, Вы хотите сделать "окно в окне" (как в мессенджерах, когда вы звоните кому-нибудь по видео, то в углу появляется изображение с вашей камеры в маленьком окошке)?
Или Вы ходите сделать окно, которое может быть не связанно с другими окнами, но при наложении оказывается всегда поверх других окон?